# Details on how front end interacts with back end?

Tags: java, spring, struts2

Consider this line of jsp code:

```
function clearCart(){
            cartForm.action="cart_clear?method=clear";
            cartForm.submit();
        }
```

Clearly it's trying to call a method on the back end to clear the cart. My question is how does the service (Tomcat most likely, correct me if I'm wrong) which hosts this site that contains this snippet of code know how and where to find this method, how it "indexes" it with string values etc. In my java file, the clear method is defined as:

```
public String clear( )
{
    this.request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();

     this.session = this.request.getSession();

    logger.info("Cart is clearing...");

    Cart cart = ( Cart ) this.session.getAttribute(Constants.SESSION_CART );

    cart.clear();

    for( Long id : cart.getCartItems().keySet() )
    {
        Item it = cart.getCartItems().get(id);

        System.out.println( it.getProduct().getName() + " " + it.getNumber() 
);
    }

    return "cart";
}
```

By which module/what mechanism does Tomcat know how to locate precisely that method? By copycatting online tutorials and textbooks I know how to write these codes, but I want to get a bit closer to the bottom of it all, or at least something very basic.

Here's my educated (or not so much) guess: Since I'm basing my entire project on struts, hibernate and spring, I've inadvertently/invariably configured the build path and dependencies in such ways that when I hit the "compile" button, all the "associating" and "navigating" are done by these framework, in other words, as long as I correctly configured the project and got spring etc. "involved" (sorry I can't think of that technical jargon that's on the tip of my tongue), and as long as I inherit a class or implement an interface, when compiling, the compiler will expose these java methods to the jsp script - it's part the work done by compiler, part the work done by the people who composed spring framework. Or, using a really bad analogy, consider a C++ project whereby you use a 3rd party library which came in compiled binary form, all you have to do is to do the right inclusion (.h/.hpp file) and call the right function and you'll get the function during run time when calling those functions - note that this really is a really bad analogy.

Is that how it is done or am I overthinking it? For example it's all handled by Tomcat?

Sorry for all the verbosity. Things get lengthy when you need to express slightly more complicated and nuanced ideas. Also - please go deep and go low-level don't go too deep, by that I mean you are free to lecture on how hibernate and spring etc. work, how its code is being run on a server, but try not to touch the java virtue machine, byte code and C++ pointers etc. unless of course, it is helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Routes are defined either by a configuration XML file or annotations--that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat doesn't do much except obey the Servlet specification. Spring tells Tomcat that all requests to `http://myserver.com/` should be directed to Spring's `DispatcherServlet`, which is the main entry point.

Then it's up to Spring to further direct those requests to the code that handles them. There are different strategies for mapping a specific URL to the code that handles the request, but it's not set in stone and you could easily create your own strategy that would allow you to use whatever kind of URLs you want. For a simple (and stupid) example you could have `http://myserver.com/1` that would execute the first method in a single massive handler class, `http://myserver.com/2` would execute the second, etc.

The example is with Spring, but it's the same general idea with other frameworks. You have a mapper that maps an URL to the handler code.

These days it's all hidden under layers of abstraction so you don't have to care about the specifics of the mapping and can develop quickly and concentrate on the *business* code.

Comment: Thanks! I now have a rough idea on what you mean. And when it comes to passing parameters, it's also in the URL, right? So the whole process is more like:jsp code ->URL -> tomcat->spring right? (Please ignore the very fact that none of the above four belongs to the same category as I'm only concerned about the "information flow" here)

Comment: Yes, for a `GET` request the parameters are in the URL.

Comment: Hey... OK. UM, is there any requests which doesn't utilize URL? Just gimme one example I'll research the rest.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think `URL` is. It's required to connect to the server, so it's pretty much a necessity. You don't go to your friends' place without knowing the address after all.

Comment: LOL I was thinking why would anything, http wise, not use URL. The wording in your last comment made it sound like GET use URL, and then there are other stuff which don't, and it aroused a great deal of curiosity in me. I mean, if you want to pass parameters over the internet in http/https, why don't you use URL...?

Comment: `GET` uses URL **parameters**, but it's not the only way to pass parameters, nor is it suitable for all situations (and it's not the "fashion" anymore).

Comment: Yes yes, so what are some other ways, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Well `POST` writes them in the request stream for example. You should probably read up on things like HTTP etc. I can't explain every single little thing to you.

Comment: No need! I know quite a few about HTTP. URL being a part of it, but certainly not all, webpages for example, are by and large HTTP strings, interpreted by our browsers.

Comment: You mean `HTML` strings? `HTTP` is the transfer protocol.

Comment: Ah yes! It resides below HTML, I believe.

Comment: No, there's no "below". `HTTP` is used to transport `HTML`, which is not a protocol but data. It's not really all that clear to you, is it.

Comment: HTTP stands for "Hypertext Transfer Protocol". I'm not sure who is the one that's not "all that clear" here. But worst case scenario I think it's tit for tat.

Comment: Okay, let's pretend that. Maybe you should teach me about things, because clearly you understand everything. I hesitated to answer this question because it could've been easily closed as too broad for example. Then I decided (a decision I now regret) to give a short explanation, as people these days don't really understand the lower level specifics that well anymore. Now you're telling me how you understand everything perfectly. The worst thing you can do to yourself is pretend you're smarter than you really are. For your own good, don't do that.

Comment: I skimmed through your comment and misread. "Which" of "which is not a protocol but data." was referring to HTML not HTTP. I made a mistake and there's that.